# Issues displaying list of builds on iOS

Tags: ios, crashlytics, crashlytics-beta, google-fabric

When accessing Crashlytics via the "Beta" webclip I can sometimes see the list of builds, but when I cannot, or if I do see them, and tap on a build, I see a message at the bottom of the screen stating

```
Server Error
Something went wrong. Please try again.
[OK]
```

I did check the Profile for crashlytics, and found the signing certificate for `*.crashlytics.com` had expired on April 7th 2017.

I removed the profile, rebooted my device, and reinstalled the profile via accessing the `check me out` option in one of the builds. I checked the expiry date for `*.crashlytics.com` and it was newer (April 6th 2020)

For the first attempt afterwards, I was able to install a build, but occasionally on subsequent attempts I saw the aforementioned server error, or the screen indicating the device is not set up for beta testing.

Can someone explain exactly what is happening and how to properly resolve this, as it is impacting the ability to complete work due to being unable to install builds reliably. Having to remove and reinstall the profile - which works for a while - isn't an acceptable method to resolve things.

Comment: Mike from Fabric here. There could be a few different things going on, but seeing your device's logs from Xcode would be the most helpful.

Comment: Next time I see it, I'll get logs from Xcode / console app from the device.

Comment: this is happening for me too on ios devices while they are on WiFi interface.. When I switch to cellular, it works..

Comment: This is a major pain for us as well. Within a day of reinstalling the certificate devices seem to handle new releases just fine, but after that it keeps hitting us with a server error until it decides to say “Well, that’s odd. You need to sign up or sign in to continue”. Ugh.

Comment: I have continued to see this issue.

I've not seen anything in the limit logs available from mobile Safari.

I do however have one bit of advice to anyone with the issue. Put safari into "private" mode.
What seems to happen is on some page refreshes, it will display the dialog asking you to accept the certificate, and then everything works as normal.

My guess is that the "server error" / "device not setup" error is happening due to some certificate issue, and private mode is causing the certificate request.

Comment: This happens all the time for the last couple years. If happening, I always fixed it by accessing Crashlytics Beta from cellular briefly - it's usually enough just going off WiFi before tapping on the Beta icon on home screen. Once the first page is loaded I can go back to WiFi. If you don't have cellular on your test device, I usually fixed it by saving an invitation e-mail or new version email in email favorites, then tapping on the link in one of those emails to take me in.

Answer (score 0):

**You're missing a final step.**

*You need to install the Certificate manually*, it would be waiting for you to install it once you get into the Settings native App.

**1. After this, go to Home > Settings (no need to close the Safari web)**

[image]

[image]

**2. Then install the certificate on Settings / Check top.**

[image]

**3. Go back to the browser and install the App.**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are having trouble with this error on iPad, check that you are viewing the mobile website (tap the AA button in the search bar and then Request Mobile Website).

Each subsequent page load may revert back to desktop, so check that setting each time it fails.